# How to make a react form that submit params to a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

So I have a react component that is made of an input field. The input field through the form submit the data and pass it to the controller. So far , so good.

Where things start to be complicated is that when I submit the form through the react component , I can see that rails acknowledges that the submit button have been clicked on but it does not capture the input submitted.

Interesingly , when I do the same with the normal rails form , the data passes to the controller through the view. no problem here.

Here is the react component :

```
 import React from 'react'
 import userInput from "./userInput";
 import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

 class InputField extends React.Component {

     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             value: ''
         };
         this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
         this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
     }

     handleChange(event) {
         this.setState({
             value: event.target.value
         });
     }

     handleSubmit(event) {
         const input = userInput(this.state.value);
         this.setState({
             input
         });
         event.preventDefault()
     }

     render() {
         return ( < form onSubmit = {
                 this.handleSubmit
             }
             action = "/get-location"
             method = "post" >
             < input type = "text"
             value = {
                 this.state.value
             }
             onChange = {
                 this.handleChange
             }
             placeholder = "What is your zip code ?" / >
             < input type = "submit"
             value = "Check my area" / >
             < /form>
         );
     }
 }

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
     ReactDOM.render( < InputField / > ,
         document.getElementById('test')
     )
 });

 export default InputField
```

and here is the controller that should receives the data:

```
 def get_location
    @get_user_input = params[:user_input]#.join.to_i
    puts "user from IP address '#{$new_request}' queried zip code '#{@get_user_input}' at '#{$time}'"
  end
```

and the view :

```
<div>
  <%= f.text_field '', placeholder: 'What is your zip code ?', id:'test'%>
</div>
<div>alert"></div>
<div>
  <%= f.button 'Check my area', id: 'button', onclick: 'getUserInput()'%>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and shell output when I submit with rails form :

```
Started POST "/get-location" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-15 14:55:12 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#get_location as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"U/a5LQTCNKnHn3ZoHfGJBAQt9tdgnK+7y7jDTmoY2iFWbuwrl/G9XacnQeIz/TCRKfT9WXPoeJgGWSRFvOdB9w==", "user_input"=>["fsdfsdfdf"], "button"=>""}
user from IP address '127.0.0.1' queried zip code '["fsdfsdfdf"]' at '15/05/18 14:55'
No template found for WelcomeController#get_location, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 27ms
```

and with rails component :

```
tarted POST "/get-location" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-15 14:55:48 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#get_location as HTML
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
user from IP address '127.0.0.1' queried zip code '' at '15/05/18 14:55'
No template found for WelcomeController#get_location, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 26ms
```

As you can see , in `queried zip code` with rails form , there is data but with `queried zip code` nothing passed.

So what I am trying to do is to pass the input from the react component to the controller through the view , but I have no idea what I am missing here or what I am doing wrong.

Any Idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: I think it's because the form you created doesn't include the CSRF token, so Rails rejects it. I'm not exactly sure how to fix it because I'm not sure how your project is set up. Here's a [react/rails project](https://github.com/Pat878/myBooks) I worked on. This part might be helpful [api](https://github.com/Pat878/myBooks/blob/master/client/src/utils/api.js).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass CSRF token into your react form component through

`<input type='hidden' name="authenticity_token" value={this.props.authenticityToken} />`

```
render() {
     return ( < form onSubmit = {
             this.handleSubmit
         }
         action = "/get-location"
         method = "post" >
         < input type = "text"
         value = {
             this.state.value
         }
         onChange = {
             this.handleChange
         }
         placeholder = "What is your zip code ?" / >
         < input type = "submit"
         value = "Check my area" / >

         <input type='hidden' name="authenticity_token" value= 
         {this.props.authenticityToken} />

         < /form>
     );
 }
```

`this.props.authenticityToken`'s value come from rails helper `form_authenticity_token`

If you use `react-rails` gem, you can pass it to your component like the following:

`<%= react_component "Foo", { authenticityToken, form_authenticity_token } %>`